# How to set name of AAR output from Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-library

I have a project with several modules in it one of which is a Android Library named (poorly) as `sdk`. When I build the project it outputs an AAR named `sdk.aar`.

I haven't been able to find anything in the Android or Gradle documentation that allows me to change the name of the AAR output. I would like it to have a basename + version number like the Jar tasks do, but I can't work out how to do the same for the AAR because all the config for it seems to be hidden in the android.library plugin.

Renaming the module isn't an option at this stage and that still wouldn't add the version number to the final AAR.

How can I change the name of the AAR generated by `com.android.library` in Gradle?

**Gradle solution**

```
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 19
    versionCode 4
    versionName '1.3'
    testFunctionalTest true
    project.archivesBaseName = "Project name"
    project.version = android.defaultConfig.versionName
}
```

Answer (score 96, accepted):

As mentioned in comments below and another answer, the original answer here doesn't work with Gradle 3+. Per the [docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#variant_output), something like the following should work:

> Using the Variant API to manipulate variant outputs is broken with the
>   new plugin. It still works for simple tasks, such as changing the APK
>   name during build time, as shown below:

```
// If you use each() to iterate through the variant objects,
// you need to start using all(). That's because each() iterates
// through only the objects that already exist during configuration time—
// but those object don't exist at configuration time with the new model.
// However, all() adapts to the new model by picking up object as they are
// added during execution.
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.all {
        outputFileName = "${variant.name}-${variant.versionName}.apk"
    }
}
```

**OLD ANSWER:**

I am unable to get archivesBaseName & version to work for me w/ *Android Studio 0.8.13 / Gradle 2.1*. While I can set archivesBaseName and version in my defaultConfig, it doesn't seem to affect the output name. In the end, adding the following `libraryVariants` block to my android {} scope finally worked for me:

```
libraryVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        def outputFile = output.outputFile
        if (outputFile != null && outputFile.name.endsWith('.aar')) {
            def fileName = "${archivesBaseName}-${version}.aar"
            output.outputFile = new File(outputFile.parent, fileName)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me, because it says there is no such property as libraryVariants

Comment: @Helmisek try with `android.libraryVariants` instead

Comment: No longer valid with Gradle 4.1: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#variant_output

Answer (score 32):

For **Android Studio 3** with Gradle 4 and Android Plugin for Gradle 3.0.0 you have to change the answer of [qix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/954643/qix) to the following:

```
android {
...    

    libraryVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.all { output ->
            if (outputFile != null && outputFileName.endsWith('.aar')) {
                outputFileName = "${archivesBaseName}-${version}.aar"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do we put this?

Comment: In your app/build.gradle inside android {}. Or you can put it at the end in your app/build.gradle, but then you have to name it android.libraryVariants.all {}

Comment: Works well with Android Studio 3.1, Gradle 4.4, Gradle plugin 3.1.0

Answer (score 20):

In my case, ${version} result in "unspecified", finnally I found ${defaultConfig.versionName} works.

```
android {
    ...
    libraryVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.all {
            outputFileName = "${variant.name}-${defaultConfig.versionName}.aar"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the outfile is "relese-1.0.0.aar"

Answer (score 19):

with the build-plugin 1.5.0 it is now possible to use archivesBaseName in the defaultConfig

Comment: This works for me : `setProperty("archivesBaseName", "${archivesBaseName}-$versionName")` with `build:gradle:1.5.0`, added to the `defaultConfig {}` block

Comment: @frouo method is working for latest version of Gradle. Should be consider as best answer!

Answer (score 16):

For the latest version of Gradle 5+, this is the best answer following @frouo answer:

```
defaultConfig {
    ...
    versionName "some-version-name-or-number"
    setProperty("archivesBaseName", "${archivesBaseName}-$versionName")
    ...
}
```

AAR extension will be added automatically.

Comment: nice .it's work well at AS 4.1.2 Gradle 6.8.3

Comment: This does not prevent the variant "debug" or "release" (or other variant) from being appended.

Answer (score 11):

In addition to qix answer here the info that you can **add multiple** output paths by this method by an regular string as well:

```
libraryVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            def outputFile = output.outputFile
            if (outputFile != null && outputFile.name.endsWith('.aar')) {
                def fileName = "${archivesBaseName}-${version}.aar"
                output.outputFile = new File(outputFile.parent, fileName)
                output.outputFile = new File("/home/pepperonas/IdeaProjects/Libraries/Base/testapp/libs", fileName)
            }
        }
    }
```

(Upvotes belong to qix - I just wrote this as an answer because of the readability).

Comment: This is no longer possible in latest gradle versions i.e 3+

Answer (score 2):

For Gradle 5+:

```
android.libraryVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.variantData.outputFactory.output.apkDatas.each { apkData ->
        apkData.outputFileName = "YourNewFileName.aar"
    }
}
```

For Gradle 4+:

```
android.libraryVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        output.outputFileName = "YourNewFileName.aar"
    }
}
```

For Gradle 2+ and Gradle 3+:

```
android.libraryVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        output.outputFile = new File(file.parent, "YourNewFileName.aar")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Gradle 6+ and AGP 4+, an alternative answer that allows full control of the name is:

```
afterEvaluate {
    android.libraryVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.variantData.outputFactory.apkDataList.each { apkData ->
            if (apkData.outputFileName.endsWith('.aar')) {
                apkData.outputFileName = "${project.name}-${buildType.name}-anything-you-want.aar"
            }
        }
    }
}
```