# How to set name of AAR output from Gradle 7

Tags: android, gradle, android-library

It's a highly discussed problem on SO, but I couldn't find an up-to-date solution after hours of searching. Sadly I can't add comments anywhere.

I'm setting the versionName and versionCode in my build.gradle using the [gradle-android-git-version](https://github.com/gladed/gradle-android-git-version) Plugin. I now want to alter the name of the build outputfile from `my-sdk-release.aar` to `my-sdk-release-versionName.aar` or similar.

However, any solutions presented did not work, because properties were not found. [The documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-tips#configure-dynamic-version-codes) on that matter seems to be outdated as well, OutputFile is long deprecated.

Going with the [newest one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63511234) I could find:

```java
afterEvaluate {
    android.libraryVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.variantData.outputFactory.apkDataList.each { apkData ->
            if (apkData.outputFileName.endsWith('.aar')) {
                apkData.outputFileName = "${project.name}-${buildType.name}-anything-you-want.aar"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

which is giving me the error `No such property: outputFactory for class: com.android.build.gradle.internal.variant.LibraryVariantData` on Gradle 7.3.3

My build.gradle goes as follows:

```java
plugins {
    id 'com.android.library'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'com.gladed.androidgitversion' version '0.4.14'
}

android {
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 33
        versionName androidGitVersion.name()
        versionCode androidGitVersion.code()

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs += [
                '-opt-in=kotlin.RequiresOptIn',
                '-Xexplicit-api=strict'
        ]
    }

    afterEvaluate {
        android.libraryVariants.all { variant ->
            variant.variantData.outputFactory.apkDataList.each { apkData ->
                if (apkData.outputFileName.endsWith('.aar')) {
                    apkData.outputFileName = "${project.name}-${buildType.name}-anything-you-want.aar"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0'
    implementation 'no.nordicsemi.android:ble-ktx:2.5.1'
    implementation 'no.nordicsemi.android.support.v18:scanner:1.5.1'
    implementation 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.13'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.6.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
}
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`apkDataList`, as name implies it is likely to use building apk.

```
android {
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 33
        versionName androidGitVersion.name()
        versionCode androidGitVersion.code()

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    /* your options... */

    android.libraryVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.all { file ->
            if (file.outputFileName.endsWith('.aar')) {
                file.outputFileName = "${project.name}-${variant.buildType.name}-${android.defaultConfig.versionName}.aar"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a single line we can edit or setting in the IDE we can change? Seems kind of absurd to have to use programming logic just to set the export name of the file.