# Why is the build aar file getting tagged with the value '-debug'

Tags: kotlin, android-studio, build, module

I created a module in Android Studio and am able to build an .aar file with no problem but see that the build file includes the value '-debug' in the name and cannot determine why.

The build is performed via Build -> Rebuild Project and looks to have run without any issues.  Also, I've been looking into different area in Android Studio to see why the .aar file is named with the '-debug' included in the name and do not see any setting that would dictate that.

If this helps, below is a screenshot of the file. A note that 'myselection' is the name of the module.

[image]

No doubt I am missing something obvious, just don't see it.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build several different "versions" of or Android App/Project. These versions can be configured in the `build.gradle` (app level) file via the blocks `buildTypes` and `productFlavor`.

While build types are for different environments like the default tpye "debug" for debugging and "release" for a release version which can be signed differently, product flavors specify different features.

Per default, android apps have a "debug" and a "release" build type. If you press the "Rebuild Project" button in Android Studio, these gradle tasks will execute for each module:

- :<your-module>:clean
- :<your-module>:assembleDebug

The modules ".aar" files will be stored in `build/outputs/aar`. To differentiate between the different build variants, your aar file has the suffix "-debug".

You can find more information about build variants, types and product flavors in the [official android documentation](https://developer.android.com/build/build-variants).

Addition:
If you want to name it differently, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26555036/9641046) explains it nicely.

Comment: Thank you for the valuable information as it pointed me in the right direction and I was able to do what I wanted to do - selected 'Build', then 'Select Build Variant' to set the variant as release (was debug before).  The answer was in front of me but I did not understand until I read the above information you provided.  Thanks again!